# can't rollback database migration in ruby on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC4Vk.jpg)i have two migration! first one creates table the second one modifies it! but when i try to roll it back it does not work!! I've tried to run db:drop, create, migrate, db:reset it migrates everything up but rollback still don't work

1st migration:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
      t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
      t.string "email", :default => '', :null => false
      t.string "password", :limit => 40

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def down
    drop_table :users
  end
end

2nd migration:

class AlterUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
      rename_table("users", "admin_users")
      add_column('admin_users', 'username', :string, :limit => 25,
          :after => 'email')
      change_column('admin_users', 'email', :string, :limit => 100 )
      rename_column('admin_users', 'password', 'hashed_password' )
      add_index("admin_users", "username")
  end

  def down
      remove_index('admin_users', 'username')
      rename_column('admin_users', 'hashed_password', 'password')
      change_column('admin_users', 'email', :string, :default => '',
          :null => false)
      remove_column('admin_users', 'username')
      rename_column('admin_users', 'users')
  end
end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC4Vk.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The down shouldn't be

```
rename_column('admin_users', 'users')
```

it should be

```
rename_table('admin_users', 'users')
```

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer was useful feel free to accept it... You'll see the option to accept to the left of my answer